# Does the containerEnv variable not work in workspaceMount and workspaceFolder, in devcontainer.json?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

Variables available in devcontainer.sjon [can be seen here](https://containers.dev/implementors/json_reference/#variables-in-devcontainerjson).

[And this shows](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/change-default-source-mount) how to use these variables to change the default source code mount.

It states that `${containerEnv:VARIABLE_NAME}` is one of them.

I tried to use that variable in the `workspaceMount` and `workspaceFolder` fields, to dynamically place the project in the remote container's home directory. Unfortunately, the variable was simple read as a string (i.e. no substitution happened).

Does `${containerEnv:VARIABLE_NAME}` not work in `workspaceMount` and `workspaceFolder`?

How do I dynamically place the project in the remote container's home folder?

My attempt:

```
"workspaceMount": "source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/home/${containerEnv:USER_NAME:userName}/${localWorkspaceFolderBasename},type=bind",
"workspaceFolder": "/home/${containerEnv:USER_NAME:userName}/${localWorkspaceFolderBasename}"
```

The resulting folder structure: `/home/${containerEnv:USER_NAME:userName}/project`